# Does the cooldown reduction buff exceed the 40% cap?

Tags: smite

In Smite, the blue "jungle buff", represented by what seems to be a blue mana potion, provides "[+5 mana per second and 10% cooldown reduction](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Buffs/Mana)" (CDR). The maximum amount of cooldown reduction that can be provided by items is [40%](http://www.reddit.com/r/Smite/comments/1rn3yd/cooldown_reduction/). Does the buff stack with items to provide total cooldown reduction >40%?
I suppose one way to form a theory to test this is to see if the buff affects one's listed CDR (seen one way by hovering one's cursor over one's magic stat in the scoreboard).

Comment: @BRoebie Is there a character with a CdR different than 40%?

Comment: No, CDR is capped at 40%. There is an item Chronos pendant that subtracts 1 second of all abilities currently on cooldown every 10 seconds. Also the character Discordia her third ability that has a similar working here is the link to the page with further details https://smite.gamepedia.com/Discordia

Comment: Sorry I meant CdR cap. Re: changing "The maximum cooldown reduction provided by items" to "The maximum amount of cooldown reduction" because you asserted the CdR cap is inherent to the characters rather than the items. I'm thinking I can reduce the confusion by changing it to "achievable by items alone". But otherwise I doubt it'd really be a problem as is.

Comment: No, there is no character that has a different CDR maximum provided by items, mana buff or a character passive.
Keep in mind that the Mana buff gives 10% cdr as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The maximum cooldown reduction provided by items and buffs is 40% and cannot be increased further.

However, this does not restrict skills-toggled cooldown reductions.

Comment: Smite is not the same game as LoL. This question might have the same answer for both games (I don't know, I don't play smite) but linking to the LoL wiki is not a source for Smite questions.

Comment: Sorry, I was unaware because I was looking for LoL question at the same time. Answer altered to Smite.

Comment: What do you mean by "skills-toggled cooldown reductions"? I can't think of any skills off the top of my head that toggle cooldown reductions.

Comment: @NiteCyper one example would be when Ah Muzen Cab picks up his stinger after his ultimate.

Comment: Can I suggest you edit the sentence "The maximum cooldown reduction provided by items" to "The maximum amount of cooldown reduction" because the first statement is factually untrue there is no maximum of cooldown reduction provided by items they provide the cooldown reduction. It is the playable characters that have the caps on stats. It is like saying the maximum amount of attack speed provided by items, the characters have hardcaps on stats not the items